# Mysterious "cannot import name" exception

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, django-cms

I have a celery `tasks.py` module which is running when imported from inside of `./manage.py shell` command but when I importing it directly from bash like this:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="config.settings" python -c "from app.news.tasks import parse_feeds; parse_feeds()"
```

It raises:

> ImportError: cannot import name Title.

I checked the `sys.path` in both modes and they are equal (except the IPython specific packages which are irrelevant).

I should mention that I have another task module which run in both modes.

**Edit:** This is my anonymized terminal output for more details:

```
(PROJECT)USER@HOST:~/projects/PROJECT/src$ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="config.settings" python -c "from app.news.tasks import parse_feeds; parse_feeds()"
/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/defaults.py:3: DeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead
  DeprecationWarning)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "app/news/tasks.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .models import NewsEntry
  File "app/news/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .permissionmodels import *
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/permissionmodels.py", line 7, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 127, in get_user_model
    user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 230, in get_model
    self._populate()
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_text_ckeditor/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from djangocms_text_ckeditor.utils import plugin_tags_to_id_list, replace_plugin_tags
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_text_ckeditor/utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cms.plugins.utils import downcast_plugins
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugins/utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cms.utils.moderator import get_cmsplugin_queryset
  File "/home/USER/projects/PROJECT/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/moderator.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cms.models import PageModeratorState, CMSPlugin, Title
ImportError: cannot import name Title
```

**Edit 2:** Make a workaround by importing customized `User` model directly, instead of original `get_user_model()`. I know it's not that pythonic but I was in a hurry.

Comment: You seem to be using a very old CMS version compared to django's version. Could you please post both versions to clarify.

Comment: Using latest 3.0.0beta2 cloned from devel .

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing management commands instead:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/